# Bat code Spigot server

Tags: javascript, java, database

When starting a Spigot server with the follow command

```
start.bat java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
PAUSE
```

I get:

> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I am using

- windows 10
- java 8 64 bit

Comment: Have you checked your PATH variable? To find out if the path is properly set:
In a terminal windows, enter:
% java -version

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**: Windows cannot find your Java bin folder.

**Is Java installed on your system?**

To check if Java can be found on your system:

```
java -version
```

**Java is installed but the PATH is not set**

If it cannot find it, check your PATH and `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.
`%JAVA_HOME%\bin` should be contained in your `PATH` variable.

To set JAVA_HOME, do the following:

1. Right click on My Computer and select Properties
2. On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html

Comment: My server is starting up yay!

Comment: Cool, but to help other user with the same problem, what was the solution? If my solution has helped you, can you upvote? :)

Comment: Idk Suddenly he did it!